# TransientPropertyValueException in unidirectional ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, jpa

I'm getting this error after some changes I made, after reading other topics. The entity Neighbourhood, for example, has entity City annotated with `@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`.

Code for example:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.enterprise = new Enterprise();
    this.country = new Country();
    this.state = new State();
    this.city = new City();
    this.zipCode = new ZipCode();
    this.street = new Street();
    this.neighbourhood = new Neighbourhood();
}

public void save() {
    if (this.enterprise.getId() == null) {
        Country cou = this.countryBean.findByName("Brazil").get(0);

        this.state.setCountry(cou);

        this.city.setState(this.state);

        this.neighbourhood.setZipCode(this.zipCode);
        this.neighbourhood.setCity(this.city);

        this.street.setNeighbourhood(this.neighbourhood);

        this.enterprise.setCountry(cou);
        this.enterprise.setState(this.state);
        this.enterprise.setCity(this.city);
        this.enterprise.setZipCode(this.zipCode);
        this.enterprise.setNeighbourhood(this.neighbourhood);
        this.enterprise.setStreet(this.street);

        this.enterpriseBean.add(this.enterprise);
    } else {
        this.neighbourhood = this.neighbourhoodBean.findById(this.enterprise.getNeighbourhood().getId());
        this.city = this.cityBean.findById(this.enterprise.getCity().getId());

        this.enterpriseBean.edit(this.enterprise);
    }
    this.enterprise = new Enterprise();
}
```

Then I'm getting `TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : br.com.shelfpix.shelfboard.entities.Enterprise.street -> br.com.shelfpix.shelfboard.entities.Street`

And `IllegalStateException` on the line with `this.enterpriseBean.add(this.enterprise);`

EDIT 1:
Added the following code.

```
if (streetBean.searchStreetByName(this.street.getName())) {
    streetBean.edit(street);
} else {
    streetBean.add(street);
}
```

Now it's throwing `PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.com.shelfpix.shelfboard.entities.Country`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by, after searching for the existing row, setting the managed bean object.

Full method is the following:

```
public void save() {

    if (this.enterprise.getId() == null) {

        this.country = this.countryBean.findByName("Brazil").get(0);

        if (this.stateBean.searchStateByAbbreviation(this.state.getAbbreviation())) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("abbreviation", this.state.getAbbreviation());
            State sta = (State) this.stateBean.findWithNamedQuery("State.findByAbbreviation", map).get(0);
            this.state = sta;
        } else {
            this.state.setCountry(this.country);
            this.stateBean.add(this.state);
        }

        this.city.setState(this.state);

        if (this.cityBean.searchCityByName(this.city.getName())) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name", this.city.getName());
            City cit = (City) this.cityBean.findWithNamedQuery("City.findByNome", map).get(0);
            this.city = cit;
        } else {
            this.cityBean.add(this.city);
        }

        if (this.zipCodeBean.searchZipCodeByNumber(this.zipCode.getNumber())) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("number", this.zipCode.getNumber());
            ZipCode zip = (ZipCode) this.zipCodeBean.findWithNamedQuery("ZipCode.findByNumber", map).get(0);
            this.zipCode = zip;
        } else {
            this.zipCodeBean.add(this.zipCode);
        }

        this.neighbourhood.setCity(this.city);
        this.neighbourhood.setZipCode(this.zipCode);

        if (this.neighbourhoodBean.searchNeighbourhoodByName(this.neighbourhood.getName())) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("nome", this.neighbourhood.getName());
            Neighbourhood ngb = (Neighbourhood) this.bairroBean.findWithNamedQuery("Neighbourhood.findByName", map).get(0);
            this.neighbourhood = ngb;
        } else {
            this.neighbourhoodBean.add(this.neighbourhood);
        }

        this.street.setNeighbourhood(this.neighbourhood);

        if (this.streetBean.searchStreetByName(this.street.getName())) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name", this.street.getNome());
            Street str = (Street) this.streetBean.findWithNamedQuery("Street.findByNome", map).get(0);
            this.street = str;
        } else {
            this.streetBean.add(this.street);
        }

        this.enterprise.setCountry(this.country);
        this.enterprise.setState(this.state);
        this.enterprise.setCity(this.city);
        this.enterprise.setZipCode(this.zipCode);
        this.enterprise.setNeighbourhood(this.neighbourhood);
        this.enterprise.setStreet(this.street);

        this.enterpriseBean.add(this.enterprise);

    } else {

        this.country = this.countryBean.findByEnterpriseId(this.enterprise.getId());
        this.state = this.stateBean.findByEnterpriseId(this.enterprise.getId());
        this.city = this.cityBean.findByEnterpriseId(this.enterprise.getId());
        this.zipCode = this.zipCodeBean.findByEnterpriseId(this.enterprise.getId());
        this.neighbourhood = this.neighbourhoodBean.findByEnterpriseId(this.enterprise.getId());
        this.street = this.streetBean.findByEnterpriseId(this.enterprise.getId());

        this.enterpriseBean.edit(this.enterprise);

    }

    this.enterprise = new Enterprise();

}
```

Comment: And entities now have `@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})`